# Moving Files From Libraries to Output Directory Not working

Tags: asp.net-core, msbuild

I have a app running on .NET 6.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
      <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
      <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
```

In this project I have dlls which I wanna copy from libraries folder files to output folder. I am using the below but its worrking,

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" >
    <ItemGroup>
        <_CopyItems Include="Libraries\*.*" />
    </ItemGroup>
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(_CopyItems)" DestinationFolder="$(BuildOutput)" />
</Target>
```

Complete file is below,

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
      <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
      <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
      <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
      <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
      <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    </PropertyGroup>


    <Target Name="AfterBuild" >
        <ItemGroup>
            <_CopyItems Include="Libraries\*.*" />
        </ItemGroup>
      <Copy SourceFiles="@(_CopyItems)" DestinationFolder="$(BuildOutput)" />
    </Target>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Reference Include="Lib">
            <HintPath>Libraries\Lib.dll</HintPath>
        </Reference>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: I don't think there is a standard property with the name `$(BuildOutput)` and your project file is not defining such a property. If the intent is to copy to the project's output directory, then the property you want to use is named `OutDir`. e.g. `<Copy SourceFiles="@(_CopyItems)" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)" />`. See [Common MSBuild project properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-properties?view=vs-2022)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wanna copy from libraries folder files to output folder

I have a work demo like below, you can try it(I copy the ExampleJsInterop.cs file from RazorClassLibrary1 to output folder). Besides, hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16420595/how-to-add-external-native-dependency-dll) will help.

1.Double-click the project name,edit the file like below:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="..\RazorClassLibrary1\ExampleJsInterop.cs" Link="ExampleJsInterop.cs">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

2.Rebuild,   I will see ExampleJsInterop.cs is copy to the project

[image]

3. Publish to folder
   [image]

Comment: I used ContentWithTargetPath and it worked